# ORA-24344: success with compilation error - Trigger APEX

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I've been working around this trigger and when I run the script it tells me the previous error message. I can't seem to figure out why it won't compile correctly, every pl/sql trigger tutorial seems to have the structure my trigger has. Code is the following:

```
create
    or replace trigger new_artist before insert
        on
        Artist referencing new as nvartist declare counter number;

begin select
    count( * ) into
        counter
    from
        Performer
    where
        Stage_name = nvartist.Stage_name;

if counter > 0 then signal sqlstate '45000';
else insert
    into
        Artist
    values(
        nvartist.Stage_name,
        nvartist.Name
    );

insert
    into
        Performer
    values(nvartist.Stage_name);
end if;
end;
```

It checks if the new artist already exists in its supertype (Performer), if it does exist it gives an error if it doesn't it inserts both into artist(Stage_name varchar2, Name varchar2) and Performer(Stage_name). Another subtype of Performer (and sibling to Artist) is Band(Stage_name), which in turn has a relationship with Artist. Why does the compiler yell at me for this trigger?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It should fail anyhow in runtime due to mutating trigger error as you are trying to insert data in the same underlying table

Comment: I read about that, I understood that the trigger shall fail if it messes with the row that was inserted/updated if it directly or indirectly deleted that row inside the trigger, I doesn't appear it's the case. My objective is check if Stage_name already exists in Performer before inserting in Artist. If it does exist (since they're relationship its a disjoint isa (Performer ISA Artist/Band)) it gives an error, but if it does not exist, it inserts in both Artist and Performer. I thought this would accomplish that.

Comment: There is no SIGNAL command in Oracle´. This is MySql. This trigger will not compile. Instead of Signal use raise_application_error. You cannot insert in the same table and you do not need to. Delete 'insert into Artist' command. This will be done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this variant (I slightly modified names of your tables).
Creating tables with sample data:

```
CREATE table test_artist(
   stage_name varchar2(100)
 , name varchar2(100)
);

create table test_performer(
   stage_name varchar2(100)
);

/*inserting test performer on which trigger will rise an error*/
insert into test_performer
select 'performer_1' from dual;
```

Creating trigger:

```
create or replace trigger new_artist
  before insert
  on TEST_ARTIST 
  referencing new as nvartist
  for each row

declare
  counter number;
begin
  select count(*)
  into counter
  from test_performer
  where Stage_name = :nvartist.Stage_name;

  if counter > 0 then
      --signal sqlstate '45000' ;
      raise_application_error( -20001, 'No insertion with existing Performer');
  else
      /*you cant update the same table, in other case you'll get 
      ora-04091 table mutating error.      
      But nevertheless this values will be inserted by sql triggered this trigger.*/
      --insert into test_artist values(:nvartist.Stage_name, :nvartist.Name);      
      insert into test_performer values(:nvartist.Stage_name);
  end if;
end new_artist;
```

After that this insert will work, cause the is no 'performer_2' in 'test_performer' table:

```
insert into test_artist
select 'performer_2', 'name_2' from dual;
```

And this will fail:

```
insert into test_artist
select 'performer_1', 'name_1' from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer. I had suspicions about the table mutating, but I wasn't sure the insert into Artist would still happen. Isn't 'for each row' redundant here? Since counter will be filled with a count query do I still need to check each row?

Comment: Hi, @Punk! "The FOR EACH ROW option determines whether the trigger is a row trigger or a statement trigger." You may insert many rows per one statement into 'Artist' table, so it seems you must do performer-existence check for each particular row. And the other one: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers.